# MYSQL + PHP one record at a time in sorted order

Tags: php, mysql

So, I have a page `allocate.php?id=XXXXX`. It basically picks up data from various tables in the database based on the id value, and displays them accordingly. It also allows user to edit and work around with related data.

Now, the main table to which the id value is associated, also has a field 'priority', which determines the order in which I need to traverse the table. Question is:

1. Say I am on page 'allocate.php?id=10000'. It has 'priority' value 1.
2. The next page, should display details for 'priority' value of 2. It is assigned to a course with id say '20001'. Basically, I wish to move to 'allocate.php?id=20001' next.
3. So how do I provide a dynamic link on each allocate page which links to the next highest priority assigned id value?

If you need more info, here is the exact table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `course` (
  `id` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `priority` int(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Here are the values:

```
TUSCE100101
Course 101
1

TUSCE100102
Course 102
2

TUSCE100201
Course 201
2

NTUSCE100202
Course 202
3

TUSCE200301
Course 301
1

TUSCE200302
Course 302
4
```

Thanks!

EDIT: To those who downrated the question possibly thinking it's too simple or I ahven't researched enough, my problem is that when I check for priority greater than and equal to, and order the result, not counting the current page, then I might be in a situation where I toggle between courses on the same priority level. Eg:

1. Course 101,102 and 103 have same priority.
2. I am on 101, the query to search for next gives me 102 and 103 in random order. I pick first value, say 102.
3. Now when on 102, the same search select query will give me 101 and 103, and the first row maybe 101. So I end up toggling back and forth.

EDIT 2

So, I worked it out eventually. Here it is for future reference.

I defined an additional column called "visit", to indicate if the particular row has or has not been visited. It has default value of 0 when not visited.

After visiting every row, I marked the visit value as 1, and picked the next value based on the query like "SELECT id FROM course WHERE priority >= $currentPriority AND id!=$currentId AND visit=0".

At the last row, when the above select query would not return anything, I set all 'visit' to 0 again, and chose the first one simply based on an ordered query based on 'priority'. This allowed me to loop through the table infinitely.

P.S. Thank you for all your help. I was honestly a little disappointed by the bizarre response from the community, though I believe I am at fault for not being very clear in my question. Feedback on my solution would be appreciated.

Comment: use `ORDER BY` for ordering. And use `LIMIT` to find your specific number. use the manual to find out how they work.

Comment: I am thinking first row of "select id from course where id!=currentid and priority>=currentPriority order by priority". Should do it right? @Touki .

Comment: @Nanne What do you do with multiple courses with same priority? Can be more than 2.

Comment: Nothing? Use order to order your courses. first by prio, then by whatever you want them to be ordered.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM course WHERE id!=$currentID AND priority>=$currentPriority ORDER BY priority ASC
```

This SQL query will give you next item.

Comment: I don't think it would. Gives me all records apart from the current one in increasing order of priority. But I think got a reasonable hint from your answer.

Comment: It wil give you the second after you've seen the first. But then it wil give you the first record that is not the second. Which is the first again instead of the third. Well.. that wasn't too clear, but the bottomline is that it doesn't work.

Comment: SELECT * FROM course WHERE id!=$currentID AND priority>=$currentPriority ORDER BY priority ASC; Maybe now it will work

Comment: It still won't work. There is a possibility that there might be more than two courses with the same priority. So you could end up toggling between the same priority level.